# How to call specific cell in excel with c sharp?

Tags: c#, excel, cell

[image]

I have an excel table with a horizontal column from 1 to 20 and a vertical column from 1 to 20. Furthermore, there is a word (string) in every cell. So, i will transfer the table to MySQL and connect it to c sharp. There will be two text boxes and a button. If i write a specific number in every text box, i will get the specific cell with the string. But for the first how do i call a specific cell ? And there a two parameters (two text boxes).

```
string query = "SELECT* FROM tb_patient_information ";
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    { //Create Command
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        //Create a data reader and Execute the command
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dataReader.Read())
        { ... }
```

Comment: Very confusing. First off: a "horizontal column" is a "row". Then you do not query Excel but a MySql database table. `dataReader` holds one row with twenty fields (columns). Use `dataReader[0].ToString()` to get the fist value, or `dataReader.getString(0)` if you are certain that the field type of the first field is string.  What do you mean with your "parameters" Unclear what exactly your problem is. Please try to formulate your question as precisely as possible and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry for confusing, my english is not so good. 
i add a pic of the table in my question (like a link).  i have an row on the top an on the left side. the aim is to get a specific cell with one of the names in it. but the there a two rows. how can i do this ?

Comment: You need to be clearer: are we talking about Excel or about a MySql table? Have you transferred the data to mySql including the numbers or just the grid with the strings in it?  Finally: I assume you want to enter "4" and "3" into your text boxes and get back "john"?

Comment: sorry for the circumstances.. 
we are talking about a mysql table! and yes i transferred it with the numbers and yes the main aim is to enter two number and get the specific cell

Answer (score 0):

OK. Your first row will be ignorable because it only contains numbers. Since the reader starts counting at 0 this is actually not bad. The first column values you can use as row index. The following should give you a good start:

```
var rowNum = 0;
var colNum = 0;

var myResult = "";

int.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out rowNum); //make sure the textbox contains a valid integer number
int.TryParse(textbox2.Text, out colNum);

if (rowNum > 0 && colNum > 0)
{
    string query = "SELECT* FROM tb_patient_information WHERE rownum=@para1";
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@para1", rowNum);
        using (var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            dataReader.Read();
            myResult = dataReader.GetString(colNum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you it is good beginning but there is an error : "invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read."

Comment: My bad. Needs a “dataReader.Read()” before the “myResult” line of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would be the direction you want to go but you can read the excel file directly with ClosedXML: https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml

```
string fileName = "C:\\Folder\\MyFile.xlsx";
var workbook = new XLWorkbook(fileName);
var ws1 = workbook.Worksheet(1);
var name = ws1.Cell("B3").Value;
```

You would also have the ability to edit and save.